# Combine rows in postgres

Tags: postgresql, group-by

I have a table with the following columns: `date, type, area, district`
I want the select output to look like this: `date, type1_area, type2_area, district`
I understand the first step is a `groupby` over `date` and `district` but I don’t know how to combine the values into a single row.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please include some sample input data, along with the output you would expect.

Answer (score 2):

Your textual description seems to imply that you want a query along these lines:

```
select
    date,
    string_agg(type || '_' || area, ', ' order by type) type_area,
    district
from your_table
group by
    date,
    area,
    district;
```